# Snapshot identifiers in git?

Tags: git, label, version, snapshot, baseline

I'm a bit confused. Is there a way to put down some dedicated snapshots, labels on a branch in git? I know, every commit is snapshot, but you would still want some label easily identifying the source code resulting build 0.9.1, right?

In other words: in some cases you might want to download a codebase belonging to a certain version of a SW. How do you find the right snapshot to download?

Comment: Are you trying to describe _tags_?

Comment: Note that a raw hash ID is as good as a tag in terms of specifying one particular commit: we use tags only because (usually most important) they *mean* something to humans and because with annotated tags, Git lets us sneak in extra data such as a GPG signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use `git tag` during the creation of specific code that is linked to some feature.

You can read more about this at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/inspecting-a-repository/git-tag and https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging.